# How i can retrieve value from selected node on Tree Panel

Tags: extjs, tree

I use following methods :

```
var myobj = myTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

alert(myobj) // [Object object]
```

Now, i don't know what i can do it with this object. I supposed this Object have my value ? But i don't know how to use Object to retrieve values ... !

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First. Looking at the API, I think the method you are talking about is

```
// DefaultSelectionModel:
var myobj = myTree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedNode();

// MultiSelectionModel:
var myobj = myTree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedNodes();
```

which returns an object or array of type *TreeNode*.

Second. I will advice you to use a client side debug tool like *FireBug* or similar to actually see what you get when calling `myTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection()`. If the result is a *TreeNode* item then check the [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.tree.TreeNode) for information about the different properties.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: There are not getSelectedNode() on Ext.Selection.Model page ?!
Can you explain, how using Object ??

You answer concerne extjs V.3 , me i use V4$

Comment: I resolved my problem : 

I do as following :

   ` var sel = myTree.getView().getSelectedRecords();
    
       for ( var i = 0 ; i < sel.length ; i++){
   
 //Each sel[i] is a Model :)  
      alert(sel[i].get('id'));
          
       }`
Thanks to @Chau, who put me on good way :)

Comment: Ahh I should have thought about which version of ExtJS you are using - but great that you found your answer :)